# Honeywell N3680 is not triggering DataReceived event

Tags: uwp, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I have device with scan engine Honeywell N3680. This engine should be support according to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support.

When I wrote sample UWP app with this code. *OnDataReceived* method is not never called.

```
async void InitScanner()
{
    BarcodeScanner scanner = null;
    var scannerDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector());
    if (scannerDevices != null && scannerDevices.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var scannerDevice in scannerDevices)
        {
            scanner = await BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(scannerDevice.Id);
            claimedScanner = await scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
            claimedScanner.RetainDevice();
            await claimedScanner.EnableAsync();
            claimedScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;

            claimedScanner.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
        }
    }
}
```

POS mode is activated and in device manager is device represented like:

[image]

If I use honeywell UWP app "BarcodeScanningApp" DataReceived event is not triggered as well.

In case of honeywell windows desktop application "POS4NET Validation Utility" scanner scans correctly.

Is there any option how to setup this scan engine in UWP app?

Comment: Is mode set to USB HID using the setting barcode at the bottom of the N3680 Decode Engine User Guide 2-1 page?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also tried setting data formatting according to section 5 in user guide

Comment: Please try to make the processing order of your source the same as this [Input and output sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-get-started#input-and-output).

Comment: Nothing, still the same. I added more events like ErrorOccured, TriggerPressed etc. and no one is triggered

Comment: If there is no answer as it is, how about contacting [Honeywell's support services](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/products/support-services)?

Answer (score 1):

@User1629894,

The device that you see in Device Manager is NOT the Honeywell N3680 scan engine that you expected.  You will see a HID POS Scanner entry in device manager when the Honeywell N3680 is configured in HID POS Scanner mode.  Only then will this scanner work with your UWP app.

Please consult the documentation for your Honeywell N3680 on configuring it in HID POS Scanner mode.

Terry Warwick
Microsoft